# How to get data attribute of elements in object using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, custom-data-attribute

I have a loop of buttons which is compiling like this

```
<button class="add-line btn btn-info btn-sm" id="cat1" data-cat="[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]">cat1</button>
<button class="add-line btn btn-info btn-sm" id="cat2" data-cat="[8,9]">cat2</button>
<button class="add-line btn btn-info btn-sm" id="cat3" data-cat="[10,11]">cat3</button>
```

In Jquery I am geeting the data as this

```
let cat1 = $('#cat1').data('cat');
let cat2 = $('#cat2').data('cat');
let cat3 = $('#cat3').data('cat');
```

but this is hard coding as I know that there are these 3 ids. I want to create an object and make this thing dynamically. How to do that?

Comment: What you actually want to do with this? Can you please explain

Comment: you can use class instead of id's and then loop through all buttons having that class and get your data attr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an object and then loop through elements using `.each()` and in loop add value of `data-cat` to object.

```js
var cats = {};
$("#cat1, #cat2, #cat3").each(function(){
  cats[this.id] = $(this).data("cat");
});
console.log(cats);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="add-line btn btn-info btn-sm" id="cat1" data-cat="[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]">cat1</button>
<button class="add-line btn btn-info btn-sm" id="cat2" data-cat="[8,9]">cat2</button>
<button class="add-line btn btn-info btn-sm" id="cat3" data-cat="[10,11]">cat3</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Identify them by some class, I have used attribute selector for now

```
let arr = [];
jQuery("[data-cat]").each(function(){
  var $elt = jQuery(this);
  arr.push($elt.data(cat));//Or any other operation to be performed
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get you correctly, you are trying to put them in an object. Assuming you know the number of buttons, this would do the job:

```js
var buttons = {};
var btncount = 3; // This is the number of buttons

for(var i = 1; i <= btncount; i++) {
  buttons["cat" + i] = $("#cat" + i).data("cat");
}

console.log(buttons);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="add-line btn btn-info btn-sm" id="cat1" data-cat="[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]">cat1</button>
<button class="add-line btn btn-info btn-sm" id="cat2" data-cat="[8,9]">cat2</button>
<button class="add-line btn btn-info btn-sm" id="cat3" data-cat="[10,11]">cat3</button>
```

Assuming you don't know how many buttons are there, and all buttons have the `add-line`, `btn`, `btn-info` and `btn-sm` classes, you can do this:

```js
var buttons = {};
var btncount = $(".add-line.btn.btn-info.btn-sm").length; // This is the number of buttons

for(var i = 1; i <= btncount; i++) {
  buttons["cat" + i] = $("#cat" + i).data("cat");
}

console.log(buttons);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="add-line btn btn-info btn-sm" id="cat1" data-cat="[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]">cat1</button>
<button class="add-line btn btn-info btn-sm" id="cat2" data-cat="[8,9]">cat2</button>
<button class="add-line btn btn-info btn-sm" id="cat3" data-cat="[10,11]">cat3</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add one new class in all button dev_class. And try below code.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="add-line btn btn-info btn-sm dev_class" id="cat1" data-cat="[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]">cat1</button>
<button class="add-line btn btn-info btn-sm dev_class" id="cat2" data-cat="[8,9]">cat2</button>
<button class="add-line btn btn-info btn-sm dev_class" id="cat3" data-cat="[10,11]">cat3</button>


// Gets the number of elements with class dev_class
var numItems = $('.dev_class').length;
var vars = {};
var newCount = 0;
$('.dev_class').each(function(){
    newCount++;
  vars['cat' + newCount] =  $('#cat'+newCount).data('cat');
});
console.log(vars);
```